# Sampling while keeping the ratio

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sampling

I am trying to get the sample from dataset due to memory issue (dataset size is 2.5GB my memory cannot take it). `df_12` is original dataframe and `df_12val` is Series which contains the abbrebiation of states and values are the number of appearances(occurences) of each state in the dataframe. I would like to take 30% of each state to reduce the size of the dataframe, but I do not know how to take 30% from each state.

I am going to do some ML modelings on the data. When I googled, all I could see was `train_test_split`, but it doesn't let me sample the data while maintaining the same ratio.

dataset df_12 is like this:
[df_12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTIqe.png)

and df_12val is like this:
[df_12val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z7k2.png)

Comment: `train_test_split` should be able to do it - there's the option "stratify" which takes your class labels (`stratify=df_12val`) and it should choose based on the class frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes so the problem with test_train_split is that it would take 30% of the entire dataset without regard to the state column you are interested to, I think for you to accomplish what you want, you need first to subdivide your dataset per state, the resample, I'll include here only the subdivision of the dataset.

First of all you need to get the list of all possible states, that will be needed to split the data by state.

```
state_names = df['STABBR'].unique()
```

Having that we then get a list of rows, in which every sublist contains the rows for each state.

```
data_list_states = [ df.loc[df['STABBR'] == state] for state in state_names]
```

and now you are going to need to do that also for the values

```
values_list_states =  [ df_12val.loc[df_12val[0] == state] for state in state_names]
```

Then we zip the data to get the rows.

```
final_data_values_list = []
for i in range(0,len(data_list_states))
   final_data_values_list.append(zip(data_list_states[i] , values_list_states[i] ))
```

Now in `final_data_values_list` you'll have sublists of your data filtered by state, and you can now resample from each list.